# How do you add Javascript Hover Intent to stunicholls Professional dropline #2 all CSS menu

Tags: javascript, css, menu, hover, hoverintent

How do you apply a hover intent to this all css menu? I really need help with this issue!!!!!!!

This is the name and link to the menu code I want to use.

Professional dropline #2
http://www.stunicholls.com/menu/pro_dropline_2.html

I have looked at alot of sites but was not sure if the code there was what I needed or not. Two such are listed below.

1. http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html
2. http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#getting-started

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to simply copy and paste JavaScript functionality into a CSS-only menu.  You will need to refactor the menu into a JS menu to stick a delay on it.  If you get stuck with that, please ask a new question about the specific issue you run into.

Comment: Does refactoring mean that I have to restructure the menu for the js script to work with it? Are there tutorials on it or an example?

Comment: Yes - you'll need to to rebuild parts of the menu so that it's JS-activated, rather than CSS-driven.  (The markup / style could stay the same.)  I found no tutorials or examples - but I encourage you to post if you find some!  :)