# Adding hoverintent to an all-CSS dropline menu

Tags: jquery, css

How do you apply a hover intent to this all css menu? I really need help with this issue!!!!!!!!

http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/horizontal-sub-nav-with-css-jquery/

Found these two sites but I have no idea how to apply the code to my menu or if it is what I need.
http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html
http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#getting-started

Comment: What's the issue? You're unable to understand this tutorial?

Comment: I guess that is part of the issue.

Comment: More so how to apply the tutorial to the menu I am using.

Comment: Please share the html/javascript you wrote so far. I possible give us jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: This seems like a duplicate question: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759237/how-do-you-add-javascript-hover-intent-to-stunicholls-professional-dropline-2-al
Or is there a critical difference that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

The hoverIntent plugin works by observing and emulating Javascript events.  Pure-CSS menus don't use Javascript eventing, so it is impossible to combine the two.

To the best of my knowledge, it is not possible to implement a delay in pure-CSS menus, as CSS doesn't track events, only state.  You may be able to get somewhere with CSS animations, but even if they make it possible, it will be a less portable solution than switching to JS-assisted menus and using hoverIntent.